# Writing a Django detail view with a generic class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I know this is really simple, but I'm missing something. And because I can't ever remember this, I'm hoping this can document a solution here.

All I want to do is pass a PK for the object in the URL and get the detail view back.

Url:

```
    url(regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    view=AdventureDetail.as_view(),
    name='adventure_detail',
),
```

View:

```
class AdventureDetail(DetailView):
""" Get a time entry detail view """

    template_name = "adventure/AdventureDetail.html"

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Page)
```

But I'm getting a "multiple objects returned error"

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /1/
>   get() returned more than one Page -- it returned 5! Lookup parameters were {}

This feels really silly. It should "just work" but I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In DetailView it is more simpler: you can just specify the model:

```
class AdventureDetail(DetailView):
""" Get a time entry detail view """

    model = Page
    template_name = "adventure/AdventureDetail.html"
```

And that's all. DetailView will do the rest of work.

Another way is to specify queryset:

```
class AdventureDetail(DetailView):
""" Get a time entry detail view """

    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    template_name = "adventure/AdventureDetail.html"
```

This will have the same result.

And the last way is to override the `get_object` method.

Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#performing-extra-work) for details

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing any other parameters to `get_object_or_404`, other than the `Page` class. So now you're basically querying for all pages. So you'd need to do:

```
return get_object_or_404(Page, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
```

Also, why are you overriding `get_object`? The `DetailView` already contains this functionality so all you need to do is have a URL with `pk` in it.

Answer (score 0):

In views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
# Import your model that you want to use in details view for example
from .models import Post

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Post
```

Then create a template with the following name conversion

```
<appname>/<model_viewtype>.html
```

In urls.py
First import the class view that you created. In our case it is

```
from .views import PostDetailView
```

Then

```
path("post/<int:pk>/", views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="PostDetailView")
```